# Delete date from a QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a QDateTimeEdit object set up as follows:

```
self.MyInput = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit(Form)
self.MyInput.setCalendarPopup(True)
self.MyInput.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
self.MyInput.setGeometry(88,25,110,20)
```

When a push button is clicked, I would like to call a function which basically erases the date value from the input box, something like this:

```
self.MyInput.setDisplayFormat("") #but it doesn't work
```

The visual result I would like to get is just an empty input box. Does anyone know how to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the inheritance picture at

http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QDateTimeEdit.dateTime

the QDateTimeEdit inherits QAbstractSpinBox which provides a clear() method, is that what you want?

http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractSpinBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractSpinBox.clear

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I didn't find this method in the documentation I have so I didn't even try :/ It gets the result more or less, but it does not delete all (probably because of the "/"); but I think I can figure out reading at the links you posted me, thanks.